# Conditional types - Why is Typescript confused about this array type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I've got a setup like so. The idea is that I want to accept a generic and an options shape, infer the options necessary from the generic and the `type` key of the options shape, and constrain the options appropriately.

```js
type OptionProp<T extends string | boolean> = {
  defaultValue: T;
} & (T extends string
  ? { type: "select"; options: T[] } | { type: "text" }
  : { type: "checkbox" });

function useFixtureOption<T extends string>(
  name: string,
  prop: OptionProp<T>
): T {
  console.log(prop);
  return prop.defaultValue;
}

useFixtureOption<"foo" | "bar">("field", {
  type: "select",
  options: ["foo", "bar"],
  defaultValue: "foo",
});
```

However, Typescript is confused about my `options` type, defined as `T[]`, and thinks that it's `"foo"[] | "bar"[]` rather than `("foo" | "bar")[]`:

[image]

If I don't use a conditional type here, everything is fine:

```js
type OptionProp<T extends string> = {
defaultValue: T;
} & ({ type: "select"; options: T[] } | { type: "text" });
```

But I want to be able to enforce that a boolean `T` requires `type: checkbox` and that text/select require a string T.

I feel like there's some subtlety of the type system that I'm missing here, but I have no clue where it is. My best guess is that the `T extends string` check is over-narrowing the type and producing a type option per member of the T union. Is that correct, and if so, how do I deal with it?

[Playground link included!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7ACgJyWAPAFSggA9gIUATAZykuAwRQHMoAfKAIySQBsIBDFAD4oAXigBvAFBQo5CADM+AV27AAan25KIALih4A3JIC+UAGRQAFAWKkK1WvSbSoAfglRQkPQCJKEXgBjYB8DKGxEVEo9PABtAF0oUzZxT3BdKB9SEh8klz1UrwyfQIALCECAa04iXOMASiNJIqgAdSQMSoZGOEj0LFwbEjIqGjpu1g4uXgFhMSk5RRV1TW0Yo1MLS0L0338gkLCI5BRo-QSkyZ3vTOyQy5S0m5LyqpqfBqbiMA7gKHklChgicoEp-AAxBAkJQYCC9E74QjDexjJyMQSWFwoPgAWwyjm6ABoXGABnp4ahMNh8IJJPUYhIXIEojwIAA6bhIRiWUnYRouWHAGEoKC8sBsxbKVQaLQQDaSSTfX7-QHA1Cg-ztTrdSHQ2EUlCI2wjBzjJgYrG4-FmxjEmRivRarpMA1Uwa0+n6RkyZmnVkcrk8gb8mSC4WigYShRSlay+WSAD0Cf0pQYlWowFKfD+xyiNFKSBU5A40AABj55FwfBc2D52HwMNX4qWoBhs+UMJ4syLLBWq5M6w2fPUEpIwRBdUL9fAEX2kLla-XGxiKwgAuQfITvU9ivsKiE7eEZ1E9LE55vMkufPFD5LljK1plK-PiZ8FUm2h10-8GNBK52CSYSgAEIx01L8dShKc4WPQ1zwHK8V3kNduA3LcpBkIo9gCfdNxcXNTlPc8t0HRsbxcO9pVWYpnzwhp32TGB2AAN2QMFuBAWQkAgSgUAAcj+AB3L8aAYQJoEzCBYT46gUCQKBBL4TjgHk7tyF4KZWQEagOwgMCICdSC9Rgvpe2Q9cLwwndfDKCpqiQWpb2je9qL0OhtFfepJCAA)

Edit: I've apparently discovered [distributed conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). `F<A|B> = F<A> | F<B>`, which makes sense as to why I'm seeing what I'm seeing now. Now, how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tracked this down. I've run into a feature called [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) which takes union and distributes it, resulting in a new type `F<A|B> = F<A> | F<B>`.

The fix is straightforward and from the manual:

> Typically, distributivity is the desired behavior. To avoid that behavior, you can surround each side of the extends keyword with square brackets.

```js
type OptionProp<T = any> = ([T] extends [string]
  ? { type: "text" } | { type: "select"; options: T[] }
  : { type: "checkbox" }) & {
  defaultValue: T;
  value?: T;
};
```

Comment: Upvoted! Btw, no need to use explicit generic parameter in `useFixtureOption<"foo" | "bar">`

Comment: Not in this example, but it was included for clarity and because in my actual use case I want the options to be enforced by the type to make sure the IDE helps catch invalid options! :)